# identifier expected?

Tags: nxt, nxc

What identifier is expected here?

```
#import "rw.txt" rw

task main()
{
    if(rw != NULL)
    {
        OnRev(OUT_A,75);
        Wait(100);
    }
}

Error: # Error: Identifier expected
```

I don't seem to be able to find a API describing the NXC API very well..

Answer (score 1):

The error was caused because the file `rw.txt` was not uploaded to the nxt performing:

```
 t2n -v -put rw.txt
```

Solved the problem.